# Laravel GuzzleHttp. Ошибка unsupported_grant_type

Tags: laravel, guzzle

Такая проблема - не могу отправить запрос через Guzzle.

```
$client = new Client(); //GuzzleHttp\Client
    //получаем токены
    $result = $client->post($request->getSchemeAndHttpHost() . '/oauth/token', [
        'auth' => ['basic', 'auth'], //basic auth
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data',
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
        ],
        'multipart' => [
            [
                'name' => 'grant_type',
                'contents' => 'password'
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'client_id',
                'contents' => $clientId,
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'client_secret',
                'contents' => $secret,
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'username',
                'contents' => 'admin@admin.ru',
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'password',
                'contents' => '******',
            ],
        ]
    ]);
```

Получаю ошибку unsupported_grant_type

Хотя через Insomnia запрос отрабатывает корректно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуй application/x-www-form-urlencoded вместо форм дата, может поможет

Comment: в content-type? Или куда?

Comment: вместо multipart/form-data

Comment: не помогает, та же самая ошибка

Comment: ['grant_type' => 'password', 'client_id' => $clientId....]

Comment: тогда тело будет не мультипарт. Насколько сказали на западных форумах, это баг 6 laravel, в 7 сделали надстройку над Guzzle, там все работает корректно. Тут пришлось закостылить через cURL